# Xamarin Bindable Property The property 'FadePropertyOf' was not found in type 'FadableImageControl'

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, bindableproperty

I'm working with **Bindable Properties**
I'm getting this error from my xaml file

> The property 'FadePropertyOf' was not found in type 'FadableImageControl'.

it looks like a cast problem, but I haven't figure out a way to make my object to read this property **ImageFadeProperty** , **ImageSourceOf** works fine. Do any one have an idea of what I'm missing?

```
     public partial class FadableImageControl : ContentView
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty ImageSourceProperty =
    BindableProperty.Create("ImageSourceOf",
        typeof(ImageSource), typeof(FadableImageControl));

    public ImageSource ImageSourceOf
    {
        get { return GetValue(ImageSourceProperty) as ImageSource; }
        set { SetValue(ImageSourceProperty, value); }
    }

    public bool FadePropertyOf
    {
        get => (bool)GetValue(FadePropertyOfProperty);
        set => SetValue(FadePropertyOfProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty FadePropertyOfProperty =
       BindableProperty.Create(
           "FadePropertyOf",
           typeof(bool),
           typeof(FadableImageControl),
           defaultValue: false,
           defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.TwoWay,
           propertyChanged: async(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)=>
           {
                var myControl = bindable as FadableImageControl;
                var o = oldValue;
                var n = newValue;
                var opacityControl = myControl.fadableImage;

           if (opacityControl.Opacity == 0)
           {
               await opacityControl.FadeTo(1, 100);
           }
           else
           {
               await opacityControl.FadeTo(0, 100);
           }

    });

   


    public FadableImageControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Also added this in XAML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<ContentPage
x:Class="animations.Views.MyPageInitComp"
xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
xmlns:bindables="clr-namespace:animations.Views.Bindables">
    <ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout Padding="20" BackgroundColor="Pink">
       
        <StackLayout Padding="20" BackgroundColor="DeepPink">
            <bindables:FadableImageControl FadePropertyOfProperty="" ImageSourceOf="ino.png" Opacity="0" />

        </StackLayout>

    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Comment: **Add to question** the xaml that references `FadePropertyOf` and `ImageSourceOf`, where one works and the other doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

This code works for me (I'm assuming the `FadableImageControl` is a `ContentView`):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<ContentView
    x:Class="App3.Controls.FadableImageControl"
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    x:Name="thisControl">
    <ContentView.Content>
        <StackLayout BindingContext="{x:Reference thisControl}">
            <Image Source="{Binding ImageSourceOf}" />
            <Label Text="{Binding FadePropertyOf, StringFormat='FadePropertyOf: {0}'}" />
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentView.Content>
</ContentView>
```

```cs
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace App3.Controls
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class FadableImageControl : ContentView
    {
        public static readonly BindableProperty ImageSourceOfProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(
            nameof(ImageSourceOf),
            typeof(ImageSource),
            typeof(FadableImageControl));

        public ImageSource ImageSourceOf
        {
            get => GetValue(ImageSourceOfProperty) as ImageSource;
            set => SetValue(ImageSourceOfProperty, value);
        }

        public static readonly BindableProperty FadePropertyOfProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create(
                nameof(FadePropertyOf),
                typeof(bool),
                typeof(FadableImageControl),
                defaultValue: false,
                defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.TwoWay,
                propertyChanged: async (BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue) =>
                {
                    var myControl = bindable as FadableImageControl;
                    var o = oldValue;
                    var n = newValue;

                    //pretend to fade image here
                    await Task.Delay(1);
                }
            );

        public bool FadePropertyOf
        {
            get => (bool)GetValue(FadePropertyOfProperty);
            set => SetValue(FadePropertyOfProperty, value);
        }

        public FadableImageControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ok I did some changes to my code I think I fixed my issue but I'm not abale to see my FadePropertyOfProperty as  a property of my object, let me update

Comment: is like FadePropertyOf is not able to be exposed i don't know ...